# Memory Leak in Foundation's Library NSCFString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments, foundation

I'm working on a project that requires extreme care with memory. I ran the simulation on instruments and it shows the next leak:

Leaked Object: NSCFString
Size: 80 Bytes
Responsible Library: Foundation
Responsible Frame: NSPlaceHolderString

I've searched all over my code and I'm not explicitly creating a NSCFString.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NSCFString is the internal subclass that's used for most NSStrings. You're leaking an NSString. It might not even be something you created — you might be retaining a string and not releasing it later.

Comment: I am using a dictionary that is passed as an argument in the function inside my @escaping closure and made [weak self] to prevent capture of self-object. however, it shows 1 memory leak of NSCFString.